# Change Mac password not login password

Tags: security, password, login

My company has setup some MS crap to handle user accounts on the Mac.
Via this frontend I updated my password.
Problem is that this only changes my login password.
The Mac password itself is still the previous one.
So now I have to enter two passwords when I restart the device.
First the (old) Mac password, then the (new) login password.
I don't think I had to enter password twice when they are the same.
Anyway it's confusing.

How can I change the Mac password to be the same as login password?
When you go to users and groups, my user, change password. This will change the login password. So when I type my old password here, it says it's not valid. Because that's already the new login password.
I asked the IT team, but they have no idea about Mac...

Comment: "MS crap" *might* be Active Directory integration. If so your IT team set it up and someone should know about it.

Comment: @Gilby I think it's AD. And you would think someone would know, but they don't 

Comment: @steros Do you have the Directory Utility app installed on the Mac? I think the problem is to do with a secure token that needs to be refreshed. It's also possible to do this from the terminal apparently. See this [link](https://www.reddit.com/r/macsysadmin/comments/ahhpdd/password_mismatch/) for a possible solution.

Comment: @NoelWhitemore thanks great find! I'm in office next Monday and will ask the IT to try this. I hope it works.

Comment: @steros The post that linked to that post suggested that you can also use the Directory Utility app to manage the secure token. Sorry I can't offer anything more than that but I don't have access to AD for testing purposes. There is also a macos application available called NoMAD that's supposed to be able to manage the Mac-AD integration better. I've never used it but it might be worth looking at after you've tried the other options if you don't have any success with them. Good luck.